# Rails 4 - showing output of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have a user model, a `profile` model and a `project` model.

Users have profiles and projects. On the profile page, want to show projects created by that user.

My relationships are:

```
Project.rb:   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
Profile.rb:  belongs_to :user
User.rb:   has_one :profile and has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

In my projects controller, I made a `@creator_id` (so that i could display things belonging to the creator). In my projects controller, I have:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @creator = User.find(@project.creator_id)
  @creator_profile = @creator.profile
end
```

In my projects model, I have attributes for `title`, `expiry_date_for_interest and`draft`. I want to display project titles for the current opportunities that are not drafts.

In my profile show page, I have:

```
<% if @profile.id ==  @project.creator_id && @project.expiry_date_for_sponsor_interest > Date.today && @project.draft == true %>
  <%= render '@project.title'%>
<% else %>
  <%= render "No current projects" %>
<% end %>
```

This is not correct. Does anyone know how to display content from related models? Thank you

Comment: @creator must be current_user..right?

Comment: please post your model associations

Comment: where are you defining `@profile`?

Comment: Hi Test - no - @creator is the user who created the project. I want the current_user to navigate to the profile page of the creator and see their projects.

Comment: Hi Amit - my associations are updated in the question

Comment: Hi usmanali, I have a profile model. It is associated to user with a belongs to relationship

Answer (score 1):

Lets say

```
User 
has_many :profiles
has_many :projects, through: :profiles

Profile
belongs_to :user
has_many :projects

Project
belongs_to :projects
belongs_to :user
```

This gives you in ProfilesController

```
def show 
 @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
 #@profile.projects => List of projects belongs to profile
end
```

On profile show you could use:

```
<%= render @profile.projects %>
```

This will render template from views/projects/_project.html.erb
On this template you can do stuff like this

```
<% if project.user == project.profile.user ... %>
  <%= project.title %>
<% else %>
  <%= "There is no project here...">
<% end %>
```

Of course this not cover exactly what you want, even i don't test this but thic could gives you direction. And of course there is many places that you could improve this code for example with decorator or with delegate

Comment: Hi Panczo, thanks for this. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to compare what you've got to my models. Thanks very much just the same.